# Can perfect play avoid "No More Moves" in Bejeweled classic?

Tags: bejeweled-3

I'm playing Bejeweled, classic mode, on iPhone.  The other modes either avoid "no more moves", or they reset the board if needed.

In classic mode a "no more moves" event finishes the game.

Is it possible with perfect play to avoid "no more moves" in classic mode, or is there some luck involved too?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually the way the game is designed and programmed you will hit "no more moves" at some point. It is random, and skill will only prolong it from happening.